# How to transform "Text(example1: "ex1", example2: "ex2")" to a usable dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I'm really new to programming, and I am building an app that is about sports and location. I am having trouble getting a specific item from a "dictionary", but the "dictionary" isn't really a dictionary.

Basically, I have a table view with rows of data taken from my Firebase Firestore data set, and after tapping on a row, I want to take the data from that row to another scene.

I've tried searching up similar problems, but the output

> Person(name: "Test3", zip: "33333", sport: "Tennis", email: "test3@email.com")

(from `print(tappedRow)`) doesn't have subscripts when I try `let tappedEmail = tappedRow[3]`

I've also tried converting `tappedRow` to a dictionary by doing `let tappedRow: Dictionary = peopleView.people[number] as! Dictionary`, but is says that this always fails and gives the error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Person' to type 'Dictionary<_, _>' in coercion

Here is the main part of code:

```
let number = myIndex
let tappedRow = peopleView.people[number]
print (tappedRow)
let tappedEmail = tappedRow[3]      <- Value of type 'Person' has no subscripts

print(tappedEmail)

let tappedUser = FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").document(tappedEmail)
```

And peopleView is this:

```
var myIndex = 0
var selectedPerson = ""

struct Person {
    let name, zip, sport, email: String
}


class PeopleViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var people = [Person]() as Dictionary
    private var document: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        peopleView = self

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

        cell.name.text = person.name
        cell.sport.text = person.sport
        cell.zip.text = person.zip
        cell.email.text = person.email

        return cell
    }

    override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        myIndex = indexPath.row

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTappedUser", sender: self)
    }
```

What I expect is that it will take the tapped row, and take "email" out of the dictionary set, and use that to call `getDocument` from Firebase. What actually happens is that I get this error:

> Value of type 'Person' has no subscripts

I think the reason is because `Person(name: "Test3", zip: "33333", sport: "Tennis", email: "test3@email.com")` isn't really a dictionary because of the `Person` in the beginning, so I want to somehow convert it into a real dictionary and then take `email` from it.

I'm fairly new to firebase and swift, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't transform anything. Please try to understand the errors

> Cannot convert value of type 'Person' to type 'Dictionary<_, _>' in coercion

means that `Person` is not related to `Dictionary`. The bridge cast is pointless anyway because a custom struct is more specific than a dictionary

```
var people = [Person]()
```

> Type `Person` has no subscripts

A custom struct has no subscripts by default. And subscripting by index is wrong anyway. Look at the code in `cellForRowAt`, there is the correct way to get the values of the struct members for example

```
let tappedEmail = tappedRow.email
```

Please read the [Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) to learn the basics.